# Rails: Check value in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model, called line_items. It contains price field. When user enters price, it can be foodio_price or delivery_price. And price field has lot of such values.

I want to put check on this. Here is my condition:

All the prices in price field should be foodio_price or delivery_price. If not, give error and if yes, give whether it is foodio_price or delivery_price.

Can anybody help in implementing it?

I did something quite dirty which is not working:

```
       @line_items.each do |i|
          if i.price == i.product.foodio_price
              @line_items.each do |i|
                if i.price == i.product.delivery_price
                  render :action => "cart"
                end
              end
          else
              @line_items.each do |i|
                if i.price == i.product.foodio_price
                  render :action => "cart"
                end
              end
          end
      end
```

It gives error of too many render or redirect calls

Comment: "not working" is not enough information. Please add the error message

Comment: @hdgarrood error is too many render or redirect calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue's in the error message -- you can only render or redirect once per action.

Try adding a `return` straight after each call to `render`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear about your logic, however you cannot call more than one `render` or `redirect` per action and as a convention you should call only one `redirect` or `render` at the end of the action.

However this might give you an idea about your logic:

```
@line_items.each do |i|
  product = i.product
  if ([product.foodio_price, product.delivery_price].include(i.price))
     #once of your prices
  else 
     #neither of your prices 
  end
end
```